# Get Iphone Data Network Statistics

Tags: iphone

**Background story:**

I am writing this because my cellular carrier claims (Orange RO) that I have used all my data traffic included in the subscription plan (which is exactly 11,79 GB) and, additionally to that, I have used 1,01 GB, all in 14 days after my billing cycle which is done monthly.

Hell, in this 14 days, half of it I've been in vacation, had the phone all the time on me and had been in places where there isn't even cellular data coverage, therefore, i find very hard to believe that I've used all that traffic.

Anyway, in my iPhone the last time I've reset the cellular data statistics in Settings -> Cellular was on the 10th of April 2014. As a result, it shows me that I have used 68 GB and it gives me how much my apps have used which all seems legit, however, considering my problem it doesn't help me that much.

**The question:**

The reason I am writing this here is because I want to know if **there is any way I can get a more detailed data usage report from my iPhone**? If it is, how?

I've got a Macbook Pro and all the developer tools programs installed.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing "who" is allowed to use your data plan (in background). How about roaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a answer to your question, but some interesting information on what can eat your data plan. (even on standby mode) !

So if you used Google maps (and did not turn it off) on your Vacation, there is a possibility to consume 100 Hours x 22 Mb = 2200 Mb

[image: data plan]

As for monitoring probably this would suit you.

[My Data Manager – Track your mobile data usage and save money](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-data-manager-track-your/id477865384?mt=8)

> Description
>
> My Data Manager is a popular app that will help you take control of
>   your mobile data usage and save you money on your monthly phone bill.
>   Use My Data Manager every day to track your data usage and ensure that
>   you don’t go over your monthly data bill and incur unnecessary
>   charges.

[image: data]